# Redirect to another URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to Redirect to a website xxx.com from yyy.com

I have this HTML code

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Redirect Page</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="get">

<input type="text" name="site" value="">

<input type="submit" value="Redirect" id="form_submit"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to be redirected to the site, I post in the input value.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST in PHP AND redirect the user to that page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546121/post-in-php-and-redirect-the-user-to-that-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have submitted your form, you will neded to detect the form submission and redirect using `header()` before any HTML output.  Place this at the top of your page (presuming that you are in a php file) before your opening `<html>`:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_GET['site'])) && ($_GET['site'] != '')){

    header("Location: ".$_GET['site']);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: the if statement don't need extra ``()`` so it could be ``if (isset($_GET['site']) && !empty($_GET['site'])){`` with the ``empty`` method it look more fabulous.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
<?php
// Make sure this is the first thing on the page you're posting on.
if isset($_GET['site'])
header('Location: '.$_GET['site']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
header("Location: $url");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
<?php

if (!filter_var($_REQUEST['site'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
  header('Location: ' . $_REQUEST['site'], TRUE, 302);
}
```